# Plotly: How to set the width of error bars using plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have this piece of code. Can I edit the width of error bars using px.scatter?

```
tab = pd.read_csv("hct.csv")
fig=px.scatter(tab, x="diametro", y="prof", color="s-c", trendline="ols",error_y="erro prof",error_x="erro diam", width=600, height=400)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified whether the width should be set by a numeric variable or if you'd just like to make the line for each error bar a bit wider. But the way to do the latter is, for example:

```
fig.data[0].error_y.thickness = 12
```

That will turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

And it won't matter whether you've built your figure using `ploty.express` or `plotly.graph_objects`

#### Complete code: